# How to install python3 on a remote server without root access - linux

Tags: python, python3, virtualenv

I have inbuilt python 2.7 and pip. I am wondering if there is anyway I can install python3 and then make a virtualenv using python3.

Comment: If you happen to run an Ubuntu, this might be of interest: [How can I install a package without root access?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/339/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-root-access)

Answer (score 1):

If you have build tools installed, you can download Python 3 sources and compile them, and then put the executable on your `$PATH`.

Comment: To add to this answer, it'll also be necessary to set the location of where the python libraries are compiled to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` environment variable. Also, if there are any dependencies, you'll need to build those from source as well and add the executable to `$PATH` and libraries to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: I tried that, it seemed like it installed successfully with a whole bunch of warnings but there were a lot of issues that came up when i was using it. Like this: `from _bz2 import BZ2Compressor, BZ2Decompressor
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_bz2'`